# How to get the level of a specified number in a factor?

Tags: r

Say, I have a factor of `data`(e.g. [1,2,3,4....]) :

```
a <- factor(data)
```

Now, I have a specified element in data(e.g. 1024) and I want to know its level in the factor, how do I make it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you want to know the numerical level that is represented by the factor string. Building on @Sven Hohenstein's sample, you could get that with

```
a <- factor(letters[1:3])
a
[1] a b c
as.integer( a[ a == "b" ] )
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are looking for `drop`:

```
> a <- factor(letters[1:3])
> a
[1] a b c
Levels: a b c
> levels(a[2, drop = TRUE])
[1] "b"
```

The argument `drop = TRUE` drops all non-present factor levels.